# Metamask injection local client standalone

Tags: web3js, metamask, web3-providers

It is too confusing for me. I tried everything.

If I run the code in node.js with browserfy.. everything works fine.

No I want to run it on my webserver. As MetaMask states it will not inject the global web3 object any more. So I download the web3.js [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/develop/dist) and add it in the html file with:
        
Ok. Now I do:

```
   window.addEventListener('load', function () {

     if (typeof Web3 !== 'undefined') {
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
        console.log('Found web3!');
        console.log('Your Account: '+ web3.eth.accounts[0]);
        startApp();
     } else {
        console.log("No web3!");
        getWeb3();
     }
});
```

But this gives me

> Cannot read property 'currentProvider' of undefined

Ok, I then tried:

```
    if (typeof Web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
```

returns:

> web3 is not defined

I also tried different thins like:

```
    if (typeof Web3 !== 'undefined') {
        var web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
```

Well, whatever I try I fail. Did I get the concept wrong?

**How can I host a website and connect to the MetaMask provider?**

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I figured it out myself.

https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md

states in the first paragraph

> Http(s) - Web Server Required
>   Due to browser security restrictions, we can't communicate with dapps running on file://. Please use a local server for development.

Nevermind. But maybe it helps someone else.

Comment: the object is still sometimes undefined and sometimes not. but this is for sure an other issue :/